# How to export Fabric JS with canvas css properties?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, svg, fabricjs

Im new on Fabric JS and Canvas manipulation.

Im using a image with some transparent space as the fabric background image. At the same time i added a css background-image for the object. That creates this effect:

[image]

not overlaying the whole canvas.

The problem is when i try to export the SVG the css background-image is not sent.
Is there any way to include the css property within the SVG file?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since one of the images is not in the Canvas itself, this is a expected behaviour. Unfortunatly, I think the "right way" is to add the top image as a object on fabric.js, instead of using it as a background.